# cython - how to iterate over c++ list

Tags: c++, cython

I want to initiate a `cpp list` in cython, assign values to it and then iterate over the list to obtain its values. A generic code could look like this:

```
from libcpp.list cimport list as cpplist
from cpython cimport array
import array

cdef int[:] c_volumecheck(int n, int comb):

    cdef:
        array.array match = array.array('i', [0]*(n*comb))        
        int[:] match_c = match
        cpplist[int] arr
    
    asign(match_c, comb, n, arr)

    return match_c


cdef void asign(int[:] match, int row, int col, cpplist[int] arr):

    cdef int j, i

    for j in range(row):
        for i in range(col):
            arr.push_back(1)

    for j in range(row):
        for i in range(col):
            match[j*col + i] = arr[j*col +i]
```

However, when I compile this I get the error:

> Indexing `list[int]` not supported for index type `int`

Given the way they iterate over cpp vectors [here](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#standard-library) I thought that would be the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ `std::list`s are doubly linked lists (i.e. each element has a pointer to the next and previous one) which makes adding/inserting elements efficient, but means that indexing isn't supported in either Cython or in C++. Instead you should use the iterator protocol:

```
# at top of file
from cython.operator import dereference, preincrement

# in function
cdef cpplist[int].iterator it

it = arr.begin()

for j in range(row):
    for i in range(col):
        match[j*col + i] = dereference(it)
        preincrement(it)
```

This is (close to) how you'd do the iteration in C++ too.

In the more general case you'd want to compare the iterator against `arr.end()` to see when you've reached the end of the list. Since you should know the length here I haven't do so.

Comment: Code is untested currently I'm afraid, so there may be small issues. The gist of it is right though!

Answer (score 0):

The int in python is not bounded to the system-bus-size, lists in C++ are using another int as indexing, an int with maximum of 32/64 bits capacity. `ctypes.c_int` should work.

Comment: I would like to try that out, but how do import `ctypes.c_int` into cython?